# set time interval between repeating audio clip in java when using clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to loop a small ".wav" audio file. The code I used worked perfectly but I want to set some time interval between looping audio. Code is provided below.

```
    try {
        // from a wave File
        File soundFile = new File("path");
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //IS THERE ANY WAY TO CREATE TIME INTERVAL???

            } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Hi. This is background music error \n" + e);
    }
```

Comment: I would try using Thread.sleep(seconds); where you need the interval.

Comment: I am trying to play 'beep' sound. Instead of going 'beep..(time interval)..beep..(time interval)..beep', it is going 'beepbeepbeep'. I have already tried "Thread.sleep(seconds);". It won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (playing)
{
  yourBeepClip.setFramePosition(0);
  yourBeepClip.start();
  Thread.sleep(pauseAmount);
}
```

The Clip is only instantiated & opened ONE TIME.

Also, the above while loop is assumed to be occurring in its own thread.